# Advice on region and language localization

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, localization

I've been looking for a solution or a 'best practices' of some sort to display content in multiple languages, while also displaying different content based on the country/region the user is in or selects. This is often requested by our marketing team.

An example of this would be: Show different French copy/content in France than in Switzerland.

My current approach is to embed these in the route like this: [domain]/[country]/[language]/[content route]

Current tech stack is a create react app for a simple application, which will most likely expand in the future. So it's a bit of future proofing. I have been looking into [linguijs](https://lingui.js.org/index.html) (with i18next under the hood), which seems to be a good option for doing localization (in react). It also lets you add locales, but only using the [BCP-47 code](https://lingui.js.org/ref/conf.html#locales). In other words: I don't think you can specify locales per region, which is a problem for me.

Anyways, I may be approaching this the wrong way. Any tips or general guidance would be more than welcome. Both from an architectural and practical standpoint.

Comment: I do not undestand. BCP-47 have fr_FR and fr_CH, and if you look BCP-47, it has a lot of options and codes (but I think no operating system includes all data). If you want more precise, e.g. Fribourg different than Jura (so at canton): you do not have it (possibly the dialects have different code and subcode, but good luck on finding the locale data)

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I'm not too familiar with BCP-47 (sorry for the confusion). So you can make any combination of [language]-[country] with it? E.g. English in Germany = en_DE ? Because that would solve my problem.

Comment: Nearly yes. BUT you need some files which define the locale. For CH, BE, etc. these are nearly always available; note: pt_BR is also more used (and possibly the default) compared pt_PT. We have the nice en_DK (which has nice ISO date format, and not muck about DK), but usually en_XX is not defined for most of regions. But the default it is to use an other available en_ locale. Personally: I use xx_ZZ for localization (dates, numbers), but not for language [text], but this depends on how you handle translation (just you can have different interpretation)

Comment: Allright, thanks for the info!

Comment: This is probably a good start: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb